# Верстка блока с учетом сохранения его позиционирования

Tags: html, background

На страничке имеется одна из секций (с закрашенной эмблемой), куда на общий div я поместил два background-а. Правый bground (фото) -40% ширины, а левый 60%. Суть в том, что все секции имеют фиксированную ширину - 1350px, размещенные по центру. Общий main 100% ширины, display: flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему не сделать обертку для основного контента? Или я что-то не понимаю? )

```css
body {
    margin: 0
}

.section {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 50px
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    .section {
        padding-bottom: 60%
    }
}

.section__left {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 50px
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    .section__left {
        width: 40%;
        padding: 50px 50px 50px 0
    }
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    .section__left {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(108, 12, 82, 0.21) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 13.54%), #F3F3F3;
        margin: 0 -15px
    }
}

.contain {
    max-width: 1350px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin: auto
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    .bg__left {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 40%;
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(108, 12, 82, 0.21) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 13.54%), #F3F3F3;
        z-index: -1
    }
}

.bg__right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60%;
    background: url("https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687") no-repeat right center;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    .bg__right {
        top: 0;
        left: auto;
        width: 60%;
        height: auto
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
    <div class="bg__left"></div>
    <div class="bg__right"></div>
    <div class="contain">
        <div class="section__left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
            ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
            laborum.</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="contain">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
    irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: Возможно, не поняли ) У меня есть общий div, как принято называть main. У него width 100%. Все вложенные секции по 1350px, по центру. Вопрос, как мне сверстать этот блок, что на изображении?) Блок, который имеет два background: правый - background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(108, 12, 82, 0.21) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 13.54%), #F3F3F3; А левый - background-image: url("../img/people.jpg"); Но так, что бы текст в левом background был, как на фото, и сдвигался на том же уровне, что и в других секциях)

Comment: В моем примере именно так и сделано ) У `.section` ширина 100% и фоновые изображения. У `.section__contain`  ширина основного контента, а `.section__left` как раз для текстового блока. Могу подробнее код сделать если нужно

Comment: Сделайте, пожалуйста, если не затруднит. Я уже "замотался" :)

Comment: Для левой секции свой background и для правой свой, которое фото..

Comment: Вся суть еще в том, что фоновые изображения этих бэкграундов должны расплываться за пределы 1350px, а сам контент с текстом должен быть в пределах 1350px.

Comment: отредактировал для большей похожести, посмотрите

Comment: Вы меня просто спасли :-) Спасибо огромное :-)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Это простые принципы описанные во многих методологиях. Например БЭМ.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вы мне вчера помогли с версткой блоков на бэкграундах. Начал делать мобильную версию сайта, и мне нужно фото (второй бэкграунд спустить вниз), а первый должен остаться на верху, на всю ширину 1350px. Я уже что только не делал, что бы спустить это фото вниз, но ничего не получается.. Можете подсказать, какой div, и что именно менять, пожалуйста. И сам бэкграунд (фото), если ресайзить браузер, то это фото уменьшается в размерах, относительно рядом стоящих блоков.

Comment: Как вариант, можете оба фона расположить в отдельных div-ах которые расположены абсолютно внутри `section` из моего примера. Дальше все просто - перемещайте их туда куда вам нужно. да и фон удобнее позиционировать будет

Comment: Дело в том, что общая структура построена так, что каждый последующий div дочерний. Как эти оба фона завернуть в отдельные блоки?

Comment: обновил код с учетом адаптива

Comment: Огромное спасибо!